# Merging 2 data sets with different number of rows, matched on a column, and creating NA values

Tags: r, merge, na

I'm trying to accomplish something that allows me to merge two datasets with differing number of rows, match them on a common column and create NA values where there isn't matching data. For some reason, when I'm merging, the newly created data frame is auto filling values that should be NA and creating extra rows that I don't want. I'm trying to merge df_add (which has a total of 6 rows) into df_main (which has a total of 4 rows) and match the 2 on column "match_id" in df_main and "other_id" in df_add.

```
df_main <- data.frame (match_id  = c("1", "1", "2", "2"),
                  index_date = c("2006-09-13", "2006-09-13", "2006-09-13", "2006-09-13"),
                  type =  c("Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad")
                  )

df_add <- data.frame (other_id  = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"),
                  measure_date = c("2005-01-01", "2005-03-13", "2005-04-19", "2005-06-22", "2005-09-29", "2005-11-03"),
                  wt =  c(10, 11, 15, 60, 42, 33)
                  )
```

This code is the closest I've gotten so far - it gives me the 6 rows that I want with the NA values but it doesn't match "match_id" and "other_id"

```
merge(df_main, df_add, by = 0, all = TRUE)[-1]
```

This is what I want my final merged data set to look like with only a total of 6 rows:

```
df_goal <- data.frame (match_id  = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"),
                       index_date = c("2006-09-13", "2006-09-13", NA, "2006-09-13", "2006-09-13", NA),
                       type =  c("Good", "Good", NA, "Bad", "Bad", NA),
                       measure_date = c("2005-01-01", "2005-03-13", "2005-04-19", "2005-06-22", "2005-09-29", "2005-11-03"),
                       wt =  c(10, 11, 15, 60, 42, 33)
                  )

df_goal
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in r? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code you provided raises in error when doing `merge()`. I am not sure you want a join though. This is no way to know that you want to align `match_id` with `other_id` in the first place. So those two variables should be called the same. Then, how do I know that the first date in `index_date` should be aligned with the first one in `measure_date`?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear - in the df_goal frame (what I want it to look like in the end) I want other_id on df_add to be matched onto match_id in df_main.

Comment: Ok, but you need to match the name of the column anyway. Could you take a look at my answer below and suggest fix in case it does not work for you?

Comment: If my solution worked for you, please mark it so that the question is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a merge operation, mostly a `cbind` by-id.

```r
ids <- unique(c(df_main$match_id, df_add$other_id))
ids
# [1] "1" "2"
mains <- split(df_main, df_main$match_id)
adds <- split(df_add, df_add$other_id)
do.call(rbind,
  Map(function(x1, x2) {
    nr <- max(nrow(x1), nrow(x2))
    cbind(
      rbind(x1, x1[0,][rep(NA, nr - nrow(x1)),]),
      rbind(x2, x2[0,][rep(NA, nr - nrow(x2)),])
    )
  }, mains[ids], adds[ids])
)
#      match_id index_date type other_id measure_date wt
# 1.1         1 2006-09-13 Good        1   2005-01-01 10
# 1.2         1 2006-09-13 Good        1   2005-03-13 11
# 1.NA     <NA>       <NA> <NA>        1   2005-04-19 15
# 2.3         2 2006-09-13  Bad        2   2005-06-22 60
# 2.4         2 2006-09-13  Bad        2   2005-09-29 42
# 2.NA     <NA>       <NA> <NA>        2   2005-11-03 33
```

The use of `[ids]` is solely to ensure that the `_id` variables are in the same order. This will run into problems if an id is in one and not the other, though if that's a possibility then it's possible to overcome that ...

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution with the package **data.table**. I have added the variable `id_row` to define a grouping order with the `*_id` columns. Then you merge on this as well through an outer join.

```r
library(data.table)

df_main <- data.frame (match_id  = c("1", "1", "2", "2"),
                       index_date = c("2006-09-13", "2006-09-13", "2006-09-13", "2006-09-13"),
                       type =  c("Good", "Good", "Bad", "Bad")
)

df_add <- data.frame (other_id  = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"),
                      measure_date = c("2005-01-01", "2005-03-13", "2005-04-19", "2005-06-22", "2005-09-29", "2005-11-03"),
                      wt =  c(10, 11, 15, 60, 42, 33)
)

df_goal <- data.frame (match_id  = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"),
                       index_date = c("2006-09-13", "2006-09-13", NA, "2006-09-13", "2006-09-13", NA),
                       type =  c("Good", "Good", NA, "Bad", "Bad", NA),
                       measure_date = c("2005-01-01", "2005-03-13", "2005-04-19", "2005-06-22", "2005-09-29", "2005-11-03"),
                       wt =  c(10, 11, 15, 60, 42, 33)
)

# convert to data.table
setDT(df_main)
setDT(df_add)

# define a row counter by either match_id and other_id
df_main[ , id_row := 1L:.N, by = match_id]
df_add[ , id_row := 1L:.N, by = other_id]

# rename other_id to match_id
setnames(df_add, "other_id", "match_id")

# set joining keys
setkey(df_main, match_id, id_row)
setkey(df_add, match_id, id_row)

# do an outer join
out = df_main[ df_add ]
out
#>    match_id index_date type id_row measure_date wt
#> 1:        1 2006-09-13 Good      1   2005-01-01 10
#> 2:        1 2006-09-13 Good      2   2005-03-13 11
#> 3:        1       <NA> <NA>      3   2005-04-19 15
#> 4:        2 2006-09-13  Bad      1   2005-06-22 60
#> 5:        2 2006-09-13  Bad      2   2005-09-29 42
#> 6:        2       <NA> <NA>      3   2005-11-03 33
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a column to join by, we can create it and then slightly modify your code:

```r
df_main$id2 <- ave(df_main$match_id, df_main$match_id, FUN = seq_along)
df_add$id2 <- ave(df_add$other_id, df_add$other_id, FUN = seq_along)

merge(df_main, df_add, by.x = c("match_id", "id2"), by.y = c("other_id", "id2"), all = TRUE)
#>   match_id id2 index_date type measure_date wt
#> 1        1   1 2006-09-13 Good   2005-01-01 10
#> 2        1   2 2006-09-13 Good   2005-03-13 11
#> 3        1   3       <NA> <NA>   2005-04-19 15
#> 4        2   1 2006-09-13  Bad   2005-06-22 60
#> 5        2   2 2006-09-13  Bad   2005-09-29 42
#> 6        2   3       <NA> <NA>   2005-11-03 33
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>